# Is there a different way to write get methods in Java?

Tags: java, methods, get

I know that we can retrieve a variable's value by simply writing get methods and `return var;`. However, is there another way to write a get method to return information on the fields instead? If so, how does one access it. For example, if I have a `planeNumber` and I want to check it against another object's `planeNumber`, is there a way to use a `boolean` to check instead of writing `public int getPlaneNumber()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two objects, java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718586/compare-two-objects-java)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are wanting to implement the `Comparable` interface? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

That is it looks like you have an attribute, `planeNumber`, that you want to use to compare the classes?

Maybe you want something like this

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Airplane implements Comparable<Airplane> {

  private final int planeNumber;

  public Airplane(final int planeNumber) {
    this.planeNumber = planeNumber;
  }

  public final int getPlaneNumber() {
    return planeNumber;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(final Airplane o) {
    return Objects.compare(this, o, Comparator.comparing(Airplane::getPlaneNumber));
  }

  public static void main(final String... args) {
    System.out.println(new Airplane(1).compareTo(new Airplane(2)));
    System.out.println(new Airplane(100).compareTo(new Airplane(100)));
    System.out.println(new Airplane(1000).compareTo(new Airplane(100)));
  }
}
```

```
 -1 
 0
 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a method comparing the field values to your class like this (omitting null check in the methods):

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ObjectWithPlaneNumber o1 = new ObjectWithPlaneNumber(42);
        ObjectWithPlaneNumber o2 = new ObjectWithPlaneNumber(42);
        ObjectWithPlaneNumber o3 = new ObjectWithPlaneNumber(11);

        System.out.println(o1.hasSamePlaneNumber(o2));
        System.out.println(o1.hasSamePlaneNumber(o3));
    }

    static class ObjectWithPlaneNumber {

        private final int planeNumber;

        public ObjectWithPlaneNumber(int planeNumber) {
            this.planeNumber = planeNumber;
        }

        public boolean hasSamePlaneNumber(ObjectWithPlaneNumber other) {
            return this.planeNumber == other.planeNumber;
        }
    }
}
```